# How to add onclick event to the array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
for (let menuname of this.tabsdata[reqmenuitem]) {
   content.push(<Anchor className="toblack" onclick={this._fetchTabData(this)}>{menuname.name}</Anchor>);
}
```

Here `_fetchTabData` triggers as soon as the page renders, please guide me how to properly attach `onclick` listener to respective array elements

Comment: That's because you are **calling** `this._fetchTabData` and pass the return value to `onclick`. `()` always calls the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are calling function `_fetchTabData`(and result pass to `onClick` I suppose that you function returns`undefined` so to `onClick` you pass `undefined`) but for `onClick` you should pass reference to function., you can do it with [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or with `.bind`

```
for (let menuname of this.tabsdata[reqmenuitem]) {
  content.push(
    <Anchor 
      className="toblack" 
      onClick={() => { this._fetchTabData(menuname) } }
    >
     {menuname.name}
    </Anchor>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `_fetchTabData` implementation to something like this:

```
_fetchTabData(menuname) {
  return (event) => {
    // Do what you need
    console.log(menuname);
  };
},
```

Then, call it like this

```
for (let menuname of this.tabsdata[reqmenuitem]) {
  content.push(<Anchor className="toblack" onclick={this._fetchTabData(menuname)}>{menuname.name}</Anchor>);
}
```

Comment: Might be worth a quick explanation regarding thunks and closures as this isnt well understand and it is a great pattern to have in your toolkit

Answer (score -1):

- `.getElementById('container').children` ---- use the .children property of parent to get elements into an array.
- Loop through the array using a `for()` loop attaching a `.addEventListener(type,function)`
- Define a function (click.changecolor) with the desired action

//PURE JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
click = {
    changecolor: (e)=>{
        e.target.style.color = "red";

    }   
};
init = ()=>{
    var childs = document.getElementById('container').children;
    for(var i=0; i < childs.length; i++){
        childs[i].addEventListener('click', click.changecolor);
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would this get a downvote? this precisely shows you `"How to add onclick event to the array of elements"` as the title states... and in the new ES6 shorthand "Fat Arrow Syntax"... maybe a little advanced for the rook who downvoted this.